# Is the following C function thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading

I saw a blog stating the below code is thread safe , but the condition `count` not being inside the `mutex` would cause a data corruption; in case two threads check the `count` at the same time but before either acquires a `mutex` and  one acquire the `mutex` after contending. When one thread completes , the other would very blindly add one more value to the array.

```
char arr[10];
int count=0;

int func(char ctr)
{
    int i=0;
    if(count >= sizeof(arr))
    {
        printf("\n No storage\n");
        return -1;
    }

     /* lock the mutex here*/

    arr[count] = ctr;
    count++;

    /* unlock the mutex here*/

    return count;
}
```

---

Would I be right if I made the following changes? Or is there a better/efficient way to do it

```
   int func(char ctr)
    {
    int i=0;

    /* lock the mutex here*/

    if(count >= sizeof(arr))
    {
        printf("\n No storage\n");

        /* unlock the mutex here*/

        return -1;
    }


    arr[count] = ctr;
    count++;

    /* unlock the mutex here*/

    return count;
}`
```

Comment: That's how I'd do it, yes. However I'm not really a MT expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are correct that the code from the blog has the potential to write beyond the end of the array.  The limit checking only works if it's done after the mutex has been acquired.

Here's how I would write the function:

```
bool func(char ctr)
{
    bool result;

    /* lock the mutex here */

    if (count >= sizeof(arr))
    {
        result = FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[count] = ctr;
        count++;
        result = SUCCESS;
    }

    /* unlock the mutex here */

    if ( result == FAILURE )
        printf("\n No storage\n");

    return result;
}
```

The features of this code worth noting

- The mutex lock and unlock appear only once in the function, and there
  are no `return` statements in the critical section.  This makes it
  clear that the mutex will always be unlocked.
- The `printf` is outside of the critical section.  `printf` is
  relatively slow, and any function that uses a mutex should hold the
  mutex for as little time as possible.
- IMO the function shouldn't return a count, but rather should only
  return a `bool` indicating success or failure.  Any code that needs
  to know how many entries are in the array should lock the mutex and
  examine the count directly.

Comment: In particular, OP's original fix to the broken code still had one bug: `return count;` accessed `count` after releasing the mutex, thereby invoking UB. This could have been fixed by copying `count` to a local variable before unlocking the mutex. I agree that it's better not to return the *count* at all, if possible, but returning the *index* of the newly-added item might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. By doing the check outside of the critical section you are opening the doors for a possible buffer overrun. However, note that the returned count may not be the same index used to store ctr. That's an issue even in the corrected code.

In order to remedy that you could rewrite it like this:

```
int func(char ctr)
{
    /* lock the mutex here*/

    if(count >= sizeof(arr)) {
        printf("\n No storage\n");

        /* unlock the mutex here*/

        return -1;
    }


    arr[count] = ctr;
    int c = count++;

    /* unlock the mutex here*/

    return c;
}
```

It's worth noting that, if that's the only function changing "count", then no two threads would be able to change the same memory position in arr and this would actually be safe:

```
int func(char ctr)
{
    /* lock the mutex here*/

    if(count >= sizeof(arr)) {
        printf("\n No storage\n");

        /* unlock the mutex here*/

        return -1;
    }

    int c = count++;

    /* unlock the mutex here*/

    arr[c] = ctr;

    return c;
}
```

If that's the pattern, maybe you can refactor that code into two functions, like so:

```
int get_sequence(void)
{
    /* lock the mutex here*/

    int c = count++;

    /* unlock the mutex here*/

    return c;
}

int func(char ctr)
{
    int c = get_sequence();
    if(c >= sizeof(arr)) {
        printf("\n No storage\n");
        return -1;
    }

    arr[c] = ctr;

    return c;
}
```

Note that will only work as long as get_sequence is really the only function changing count variable.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the previous answers, but there is a better way. A mutex is not needed.

```
int func(char ctr) {
    int c = interlocked_increment(&count);
    if (c >= sizeof(arr)) {
        printf("\n No storage\n");
        interlocked_decrement(&count);
        return -1;
    }
    arr[c-1] = ctr;
    return c;
}
```

This depends on the availability of interlocked increment and decrement functions, which have to be provided by your operating system or third party library.

---

Every value of `c` that is within range is guaranteed to be one not seen by any other thread, and is therefore a valid slot in `arr`, and no thread will miss a slot if there is one available. The order of storing the value is indeterminate, but that is true of most of the other solutions too. The maximum value reached by `count` if many threads are competing for storage is also indeterminate, and if that is an issue a different approach might be needed. The behaviour if `count` is decremented is another unknown. This stuff is hard, and it's always possible to add additional constraints to make it harder.

---

Just to point out that there is another possible implementation based on a CSET (Check and Set) function. This is a function that checks whether some location is equal to a value and if so sets it to another value atomically, returning true if so. It avoids some of the criticism leveled at the above function.

```
int func(char ctr) {
    for (;;) {
      int c = count;
      if (c >= sizeof(arr)) {
        printf("\n No storage\n");
        return -1;
      }
      if (CSET(&count, c, c+1)) {
        arr[c] = ctr;
        return c;
      }
  }
}
```

The C++ standard atomic operations library contains a set of atomic_compare_exchange functions which should serve the purpose, if available.

Comment: In principle, unless you have a bound on the number of threads, this could overflow `count` momentarily and thus cause the comparison `c>=sizeof(arr)` to wrongly evaluate to false. It's unlikely that would happen in practice, but I'm pointing this out to show how difficult it really is to write safe, fully-general code using atomics; even things that look trivially right might not be. There might also be a concern with the n'th entry possibly being written *after* the n+1 entry; this could be a problem if you assume all values up to the returned index are valid after return.

Comment: I disagree. Every `c` that is within range is a valid slot in `arr` and none will be missed. I agree this stuff is hard, but this solution works for this problem and is a good way to approach others that are similar. See edit.

Comment: If threads A and B call `func('a')` and `func('b')` and they return 0 and 1, respectively, it's still possible that, at the time `func('b')` returns, `'a'` has not yet been written into the array. That cannot happen with the mutex-based solution. Whether it matters depends on the application. The overflow issue can definitely happen if more than `UINT_MAX` threads all call `func` at the same time, but it's doubtful that so many threads could exist.

Comment: @R: I have already agreed that the store operation is unordered, as for 2 out of 3 of the other solutions. I do not accept that a solution should be required to work for UINT_MAX threads unless that is an explicit (impossible) requirement. The advantage of this method is that it is immune to the race condition of the OP.